# What's behind PLS regression method?

Tags: regression, pca, data-visualization, prediction, partial-least-squares

I was wondering if anyone could provide me a source with a more or less simple explanation to the  PLS regression process? I have been reading [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nicole_Kraemer/publication/220728917_Overview_and_Recent_Advances_in_Partial_Least_Squares/links/09e41513dd2c3c9ab7000000.pdf) paper to help me understand what's behind the PLS, but I got somewhat lost in the part explaining the algorithms the regression, specially because my algebra knowledge is somewhat rusty. Can anyone suggest a source that explains the regression part well enough to be in a master thesis, but simple enough to be more accessible? If you don't have a source but can explain it to me (even without mathematical formulas, just theoretically) I would also greatly appreciate it!

Comment: there is no simple explanation of PLS

Comment: Hi: I think for the plain old OLS case ( someone correct me if I'm wrong ), it goes like this. Suppose you have the OLS, $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$. Then, what you're doing geometrically in  OLS, is finding the line that minimizes the ( sum of the vertical distances) squared between each point $y_{i}$ and the line. In PLS, rather than minimizing the sum of the (vertical distances) squared, you find the line that minimizes the sum of the (perpendicular distances) squared between each point $y_{i}$ and the line. But, based on the link you referenced, the general case is WAY more complicated.

Comment: @mlofton yes, the PLS mathematical explanaition seems to be indeed very complex... I think I'm just going to have to study a bit more of algebra all over again!

Comment: Hi: It looks REALLY complex. But, if you are just interested in the simple regression case, then I think what I said is correct.